# Internet explorer 11 under windows 10 does not play HTML5 videos

Tags: windows-10, video, internet-explorer-11, html5

For some reason, my internet explorer just will not recognized HTML5 videos. I'm fairly certain that my computer is at fault, because my colleague has tested it with his W10 IE11, and it works.

When visiting the [HTML5 Youtube test page](https://www.youtube.com/html5), it looks like this:

[image]

But that means the browser doesnt even recognize the `<video>` tag?! When I open a video on youtube, it gets delivered with flash.

I read somewhere that it might be because of a missing media feature pack, but I already have that installed. I've also tried running it in compatibility view and other document views but to no avail. Please help.

Comment: You mean Edge or Internet Explorer?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 as the title suggests.

Comment: You do realize MS recommends Edge over IE and it comes with Windows 10.

Comment: Yes. This isn't about my usage. A customer has the same problem and I hope to solve it by making it work on my system. I'm using chrome privately.

Comment: You sure it doesn't? I'm using Windows 10 and IE 11 can play HTML 5 video. Try this page http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp if this doesn't work the next step is to narrow it down to the cause. Can you play other types of video?

Comment: It does not. The video-file does not get downloaded. [Image](http://i.imgur.com/YPZgBb0.png) . That leads me to believe that the filetype isn't recognized and therefore skipped. The browser however does recognize that a video should be displayed because the controls are shown.

Comment: Can you play flash videos like on Netflix? You can try youtube, but be warned that if Netflix can't play flash it may try HTML5.

Comment: try following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124885/html5-video-not-working-in-ie-11

Comment: Solved it. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my media feature pack was the problem. I already had this in mind and tried reinstalling the **latest version from the Microsoft website** but it's the wrong one for some reason. After some research, I found a fixed version [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229), now it works. I have no idea why it didn't work in the first place.

Elaboration: When googling for the media feature pack for Windows 10, the first hit is [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231) (KB3010081). The aforementioned page, containing the fixed update KB3099229,  however states that it supersedes the KB3010081 pack.

Comment: This happens when you had the media pack installed, upgraded to Version 1511, then failed to upgrade the pack after you did so.  I went ahead and removed the rant contained in this answer, and the masked profanity, profanity in any form is not acceptable content.

Comment: Sorry for the profanity.